# Which distribution do reddit link scores follow?

Tags: distributions, modeling

I'm trying to model the distribution of link scores (number of upvotes minus number of downvotes) on reddit, for a single subreddit at a time.

For example, here are some histograms of post scores on /r/linux, with all values included (shifted by 0.1 so that I can use a log scale and still display 0 value posts), and with scores greater than 1 only:

[image: Histograms of scores]

Is there a classical distribution, ideally without too many parameters, that would fit this well?

Comment: Have you tried fitting some distributions? If not, try gamma, negative binomial, and Weibull to start.

Comment: In many statistical applications, knowing the distribution of some data set is actually not an essential step to learning from the data. What problem are you trying to solve, and how does knowing the distribution help you solve it?

Comment: @Sycorax: I'm trying to estimate the probability of a post reaching a certain score and above, especially for high scores. I'm thinking that a good model can help, especially for low-traffic subreddits. I'm also trying non-parametric approaches in parallel, such as sklearn's QuantileTransformer.

Comment: A model will impose assumptions, either implicit or explicit, on the distribution, whence all your conclusions will depend to some degree on those assumptions.  The nature of this distribution is such that those assumptions will have to be extremely complicated and likely unwarranted, suggesting you instead proceed to use *the data themselves* directly for the estimates.